# How to set up development environment for yql and open table development? How to test it locally? (best practice)

Tags: testing, yahoo, yql

I develop -- from time to time -- yahoo open tables to access different resources on the web. Currently I am using a JavaScript editor and -- when I want to test if my open table works -- I upload the xml table description to a server to test it with a yql client application. However this approach is quite slow and -- sometimes -- I get blocked by yahoo, because of a mistake in my open table description. Therefore I would like to learn about best practices on how to test and develop yahoo open table locally. How does look your set up for the open table development?

To clarify my question, I am looking for any convenient way (best practise) to develop and test yql tables, e.g., running a part of a Java Script inside [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Comment: I do not understand your problem of getting blocked by Yahoo because I have not experienced that issue. Can you elaborate on that? In which situations do you get blocked and what kind of error messages do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: I agree that I don't see a really convenient way either to test YQL datatable definitions locally. Nevertheless, here is how I approach this issue.

### Hosting on github

YQL datatable definitions are often used in very open scenarios e.g. when there is an existing API that you want to wrap via YQL. Therefore I am normally working on a fork of the YQL community tables and I just add my own definitions there. The hosting of the .xml files takes place on github in this case: https://github.com/yql/yql-tables

The other advantage of this approach is as well that it is easy for me to share my datatables with the community if I feel that they might be valuable for others as well.

### Hosting privately

The free github account only comes with free repositories though, so everybody would be able to see and use your datatables. If that is not good for you then you could either buy a github pro account to get private repositories, or host the datatable definitions yourself.

To do that you can upload them to your own server - as you are already doing - or you should also be able to set up a web server like Apache locally on your machine and then get a dynamic hostname from [dyndns.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) or similar, so that you can point to this definitions from YQL. I have not tried this because github was working sufficiently well for me but I am sure that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the file you are editing in a public dropbox folder? This is what I do and it works pretty well.

Comment: Just in case anybody is wondering: I believe davidk01 is referring to https://www.dropbox.com